Specification of Token Lists
Are Token Lists specific to the expl3 layer, or are they more general entities within latex ?

See the tokcycle package, https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle, for some non-expl3 tools for dealing with lists of tokens.

everything in tex is a list of tokens. L3 names these as token lists and uses parameterless macros as "token list variables" to hold such a list.
An expl3 "string" (str datatype) is also a list of tokens at the TeX level but here restricted to catcode 12 ("other") apart from spaces which are catcode 10.
expl3 is not an extension of the tex engine it is a set of macros written in TeX (as is latex2e) so there is nothing that is really unique to the expl3 layer, which is a set of conventions to formalise handling of tex constructs and a large library of useful functions.
